# prestashop 1.6 get values from tpl product-list by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, task-parallel-library, prestashop, smarty

I'm using prestashop 1.6, and i'm trying to goal this:
 - in product list i created a add quantities buttons

```
<!------------------------ quantity wanted ---------------------------------------------->
        {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
        <p class="quantity_wanted_p_"{if (!$allow_oosp && $product->quantity <= 0) || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: block;"{/if}>
        <!-- <label>{l s='Quantity'}</label> -->
            <a class="btn button-minus product_quantity_down decrement_qty" data-field-qty="{$product.minimal_quantity}">
                <span><i class="icon-minus"></i></span>
            </a>
            <input type="number" min="1" name="qty" id="quantity_wanted_{$product.id_product|intval}" class="text inputqtyfield" value="{if isset($quantityBackup)}{$quantityBackup|intval}{else}{if $product.minimal_quantity > 1}{$product.minimal_quantity}{else}1{/if}{/if}" />
            <span class="minQty" style="display:none;">{$product.minimal_quantity}</span>
            <a class="btn button-plus product_quantity_up increment_qty">
                <span><i class="icon-plus"></i></span>
            </a>
            <span class="clearfix"></span>
        </p>
        {/if}
```

- in global js file i created this to the + and - button and work

  ```
  /////quantities in  default product list
  ```

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.increment_qty').click(function() {
        var oldVal = $(this).parent().find("input").val();
          if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 0 ) {
          var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) + 1;
          $(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
        }
      });

  ```
  $('.decrement_qty').click(function() {
    var oldVal = jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val();
    if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 1 ) {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) - 1;
      $(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    }
  });
  ```

  });
- and all works well, but now i wanna increase or decrease with minimal quantity instead of 1, so if the product has 10 of minimal buy when the customer click on + button the result is 20, another click 30 and so on...but i cant get the minimal quantity in this file global.js, **any ideias how to achive this?**